# How do I utilize all the OData functions in the $filters parameter in azure cognitive search?

Tags: azure, odata, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to apply filters in azure cognitive search. I am finding it difficult to apply further advanced filters such as using dayOfWeek() . For example

```
$filter=TimeSlots/any(dt: contains(isof(dt, 'Edm.String'), 'Mon')) 
or
$filter=TimeSlots/any(dt: dayOfWeek(dt) eq 0) //to find if the date is a Sunday
```

I always seem to get an error when i try these types of queries in the azure search.
I also can't use the "contains" function with the filters.
"Invalid expression: No function signature for the function with name 'contains' matches the specified arguments. The function signatures considered are: contains(Edm.String Nullable=true, Edm.String Nullable=true).\r\nParameter name: $filter"

I have tried looking at a few documentations and found that OData V4 is being used in azure search but these are not supported in that version. So how do I accomplish the results that I want.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Cognitive Search [only supports a subset of OData functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-odata-filter-orderby-syntax) and does not currently support `dayOfWeek`. You can search inside of collections using `any`.

The following should work assuming that `TimeSlots` contains strings such as `Mon`,`Tue`, etc.. If `TimeSlots` only contains the full date then consider adding a separate field that makes querying this data possible with the supports OData functions:

```
$filter=TimeSlots/any(dt: dt eq 'Mon')
```

There are more examples available for [`any` here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-odata-collection-operators) and for [comparison operators, such as `eq`, here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-odata-comparison-operators#examples).